# Что делать при предупреждении - The local function 'CheckGround' is declared but never used?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Решил изучить юнити по уроку, а точнее по [курсу](https://unity3dschool.ru/unity-bazovyj-kurs-2d.html) "Юнити - 2D платформер с нуля".

Написал такой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform groundChek;
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float Speed;
public float jumpHeight;
bool isGrounded;
void Start()
{
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


void Update()
{
Flip();
CheckGround();
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Speed, rb.velocity.y);
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded) {
rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
}

void Flip () {
if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) {
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) {
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
}
}
void CheckGround () {

Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.posithion, 0.2f);
isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если у вас пропадает желание работать от того, что вы не можете прочитать и перевести ошибку, то у меня для вас плохие новости. Причем это даже не ошибка, а предупреждение, ошибки - красные. Вы объявили метод `CheckGround`, но нигде его не вызываете. Если вас демотивируют такие простые вещи настолько, что "все желание работать пропадает", то, может быть вы и не хотите этим заниматься?

Comment: Почему вы требуете от кого то помощи? Будто бы потерять Вас, "крутого" разработчика очень болезненно. Судя по модификаторам доступа и впринцыпе разъяснениям, Вы выбрали не того учителя и стали не на тот путь. Пересмотрите свое отношение к новому делу

Comment: жаль видеть таких как вас токсиков я ничего не требую а лишь прошу помощи от боллее опытных програмистов

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев Жаль видеть таких как вы - людей, которые не хотят потратить 5 минут, загуглить ошибку и самостоятельно решить ее, зато плодят на форумах однотипные вопросы и ждут по 15 часов ответа. Вы просто ищете оправдания, чтобы ничего не делать. Появилась ошибка - все плохо, я демотивирован, не буду сегодня ничего делать. Написали комментарий с критикой - все токсики, никто не хочет помогать. Получите сначала базовые знания C# о том, что такое область видимости и проблема решится сама собой.

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев жаль, действительно... Жаль, что вы на форуме... Жаль, что такие программисты существуют

Comment: уважаемый я искал данную прблему но не нашел ответа плюсом в уроке все работает я прошел уроки по си шарп до темы ооп именно для того чтобы мне не писали такие как вы

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев Судя по всему, прошли уроки по си шарп вы мимо, раз не знаете что такое область видимости и, что если объявить метод в методе, то вне этого метода он работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

```
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _groundCheckTransform;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpHeight;

    private Rigidbody2D _rb;
    private bool _isGrounded;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        Flip();
        CheckGround();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * _speed, _rb.velocity.y);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _isGrounded) 
        {
            _rb.AddForce(transform.up * _jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void Flip () 
    {
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) 
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) 
            {
                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
            }
        }
    }  

    private void CheckGround() 
    {    
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(_groundCheckTransform.position, 0.2f);
        _isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
    }    
}
```

Проблема была в одной неправильно поставленной точке с запятой и фигурной скобке. Но в тоже время прощу обратить внимание на то, как я переписал ваш код. У вашего кода были явные проблемы с внешним видом :)

И лично от себя добавлю: я конечно не посягаюсь на курс Unity3DSchool, но в плане качества кода (да и в целом) он не очень хорош ;)

Comment: очень признателен! но только сейчас юнька выдает ошибку : error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration честно не могу понять какая ошибка допущена в 13 строке подскажите!

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев Очень странно, что только одну ошибку, потому что у меня Visual Studio показывает 7. Во-первых, у поля `_isGrounded` не объявлен тип, должен быть `bool`. Во-вторых, поле называется `_rb`, а в 26 строке, в методе `FixedUpdate` используется `rb.velocity.y`, поля `rb` просто не существует. В-третьих, в 47 строке _groundCheсkTransform вручную переписать нужно, если будет ошибка.

Comment: @KOTlK код писал без Visual Studio, так что извиняюсь за небольшие опечатки и недосмотры с моей стороны. Теперь код должен работать.

Comment: код выдает три ошибки error CS0103: The name '_groundCheckTransform' does not exist in the current context
 Field 'Player._speed' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0
Field 'Player._jumpHeight' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев первая ошибка скорее всего из-за того, что одна из латинских букв "c" была русской "с". А вторая и третья в дословном переводе указывают на то, что поля обозначены, но им никогда не присваиваются значения. (Это даже не ошибка, а предупреждение)

Comment: @АЛекснадрГрачев Как я и написал ранее, `в 47 строке _groundCheсkTransform вручную переписать нужно, если будет ошибка.` Пишу снова: Желтые ошибки - предупреждения и код скорее всего будет работать, красные - критические и код работать не будет. Вы точно знаете основы c#?

Answer (score 0):

Вы сделали локальный метод Check Ground, но нигде в коде или вне кода(хотя локальные переменные из вне кода вы не сможете использывать) его не используете